# Why is return used in onclick event handler?

Tags: javascript

Why is "return" used in the onclick even handler below, seems to function with or without the return specification in the onclick event for the buttons?

```
input type="radio" name="radCPUSpeed" value="6 Ghz"
                       onclick="return radCPUSpeed_onclick(2)"
```

The function does not seem to do anything with it, why do you need return in the input declaration above?

```
function radCPUSpeed_onclick(radIndex)
   {
       var returnValue = true;
       if (radIndex == 1)
       {
           returnValue = false;
           alert("Sorry that processor speed is currently unavailable");
           // Next line works around a bug in IE that doesn't cancel the
           // Default action properly
           document.form1.radCPUSpeed[radCpuSpeedIndex].checked = true;
       }
       else
       {
           radCpuSpeedIndex = radIndex;
       }
       return returnValue;
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Returning `false` from an event handler function will prevent the default browser behaviour associated with the event. Returning any other value (including `undefined`, which is what is returned if no `return` statement is executed) will not. Importantly, returning `false` does **not** prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, and an event handler attached to a node higher up the DOM tree will still be executed.

Note also that this does not apply to event listener functions attached via `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`. The return value in such functions has no effect.

Comment: Thanks, but why is "return" needed at the beginning of the "onclick=" below:

input type="radio" name="radCPUSpeed" value="6 Ghz" 
                       onclick="return radCPUSpeed_onclick(2)"

Comment: You can imagine the value of an event handler attribute as the body of a function that is called when the event fires. Returning `false` from this function prevents the default browser action.

Comment: This is an excellent answer summarizing it all, assuming it is all correct, Important points: 1. Returning undefined is not the same as returning false.  2. Return-value of handlers added with addEventListener() or attachEvent() have NO EFFECT.  3. Returning false from HTML-embedded event-handlers cancels the default behavior but does NOT stop event-bubbling.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you return `false` from any event handler the event will not bubble up. So lets say normally this button will submit a form, when you return `false` this will not happen. Essentially it will prevent the default action of the event.

Comment: While it's true that the event does not bubble up, the behavior you described has to do with preventing the default action.

Comment: To be clear, the event **does** still bubble, but the part about preventing the default browser action is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,the value or whatever comes after the '=' sign is a function in case of an event handler.
As a reason,return must be used so that the function returns a boolean value to the event handler-onclick,onsubmit etc.

```
onclick="return radCPUSpeed_onclick(2)
```

The above code can be interrupted as:
    onclick="function(){radCPUSpeed_onclick(2)}
Therefore,whatever comes after the equal to sign is actually inside a function and a return statement is required.